# Incompatibility between lipics and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, pdftex

I am using the lipics document class. I want to use the hyperref package with this and pass some parameters to it. When I use this code,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,UKenglish]{lipics}
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=false,pdfstartpage=5]{hyperref}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.
```

When I try the following code,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,UKenglish,hyperref={bookmarks=false,pdfstartpage=5}]{lipics}
```

I am getting 469 errors and the first one is:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

What is the right way to combine lipics and hyperref?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). You could try `\RequirePacakge[pdftex,bookmarks=false,pdfstartpage=5]{hyperref}` _before_ `\documentclass`?

Comment: @peter-grill: The code you mentioned, gives the following warning: `Package hyperref Warning: Option 'pdfpagelabels' is turned off (hyperref) because \thepage is undefined.`

Comment: @peter-grill: and the following errors: `! LaTeX Error: Command \maketitle already defined.`  `! LaTeX Error: Command \appendix already defined.`

Comment: @Ok, I did not have the `lipics` class so was not able to test it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\hypersetup`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,UKenglish]{lipics}
\hypersetup{bookmarks=false,pdfstartpage=5}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

This suppresses the errors, but still leaves a warning:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Option `bookmarks' has already been used, setting the option has no effect on input line 2
```

To suppress the bookmarks, you can use the `bookmark` package and its `depth` option:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,UKenglish]{lipics}
\hypersetup{pdfstartpage=5}
\usepackage[depth=0]{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\begin{document}
\section{test}
\lipsum[1-90]
\end{document}
```